# JavaScript: Concatenate variable inside FindControl

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages, nullreferenceexception, getelementbyid

I'm using Master Pages on ASP.NET, I'm trying to use a Javascript function to handle the 'onkeypress' event of many TextBox, but when I try get the control I get the following error:

> "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function txtValidation(sender) 
   {
      var txt = document.getElementById('<%=Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("' + sender + '").ClientID %>');  
      txt.Value = "Ok"
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do.  Here are some things that might help:

The "sender" parameter passed is already a reference to the dom object. If you want it client side, `sender.Value = "Ok";` will work.

Looking at your code ... are you trying to take a TextBox, and, when the user presses a key, instantly change the text to "Ok"?  Then try this:

```
function txtValidation(sender)
{
  sender.Value = "Ok";
}
```

As a bonus tip which might be relevant, if your code is in an external .js file it won't be parsed by your asp.net page handler and your `<%= .. %>` blocks won't work.  You can get around this easily if you're using jQuery with the attribute selector:

```
$("[id$='foo']")
```

This will match all elements with an asp.net ID of `foo`, since the generated client ID will be something like `$Namingcontainer1$Naming2$Naming3$foo`